# Hiding DialogSheets [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have problem with hide my custom dialog frame. After pressing buttons (they have calls to other macros), I still have my dialog frame, how to hide it?
I am working in "Dane_Makro" sheet.
My previous version worked fine (i did not add 2 additional buttons, but i edited vbYesNo buttons - the scheme was very similar)
Regards

[Source of dialogsheets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2012/03/05/customizing-your-messages-with-dialog-sheets/)

```
'Public btnDlg As DialogSheet

Sub CallBots()

Dim btnDlg As DialogSheet
Dim ButtonDialog As String
ButtonDialog = "CustomButtons"
Dim klik As Boolean
klik = True


Dim oSHL As Object: Set oSHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets(ButtonDialog).Delete
Err.Clear
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set btnDlg = ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets.Add


With btnDlg
    .Name = ButtonDialog
    .Visible = xlSheetHidden

    With .DialogFrame
        .Height = 70
        .Width = 300
        .Caption = "Generowanie plików do BOTÓW"
    End With

    .Buttons("Button 2").Visible = False
    .Buttons("Button 3").Visible = False
    .Labels.Add 100, 50, 100, 100
    .Labels(1).Caption = "Jak utowrzyć pliki wsadowe do botów?"

    .Buttons.Add 220, 44, 130, 18 'Custom Button #1,index #3
    With .Buttons(3)
        .Caption = "Nowe pliki wsadowe"
        .OnAction = "MakeBotsNew"
    End With


    .Buttons.Add 220, 64, 130, 18 'Custom Button #2,index #4
    With .Buttons(4)
        .Caption = "Konsolidacja plików wsadowych"
        .OnAction = "MakeBotsConso"
   End With


    If .Show = False Then
        oSHL.PopUP "Anulowanie procesu", 1, "Tworzenie plików", vbInformation
        klik = False
    End If

End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'On Error Resume Next
    DialogSheets("CustomButtons").Delete
    Err.Clear
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    btnDlg.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer Updated:

You're going to need to add an (optional?) argument to your `MakeBotsNew` and `MakeBotsConso` macros, like so:

```
Sub MakeBotsNew(Optional Name As String = "")
    'Existing Code here

    'After existing code:
    If Len(Name) > 0 Then ThisWorkbook.DialogSheets(Name).Hide 'Hide dialog box
End Sub
```

Then, you need to add the ButtonDialog name as an argument to the `.OnAction`, which also means wrapping it it single-quotes:

```
.OnAction = "'MakeBotsNew """ & ButtonDialog & """'"
```

(I still don't understand **A)** why you are creating your Dialog in code instead of doing it beforehand and **B)** why you are using a DialogSheet instead of a UserForm)

### Old Answer:

<s>As a DialogSheet is a **Sheet**, you need to set the `.Visible` property to `xlSheetHidden` or `xlSheetVeryHidden`</s>

Using `.Hide` is for [UserForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/create-a-custom-dialog-box), which replaced DialogSheets back in... 2000?

Comment: I have replaced `.Hide` to `.Visible = xlSheetHidden`
Still does not work. Wrong place?

Comment: Comment out your `On Error Resume Next` line, or add a `On Error GoTo 0` line, and see if it gives you an error message that tells us what is wrong

Comment: I made some corrections in code. To sum up, my `On Error Resume Next` is only protecting(check if dialogsheets("custombuttons") exists. So, code works. Pressing X makes it not displayed (Perfect).
But pressing button #3 or button #4 cant makes my dialog frame invisible, deleted etc.

Comment: Added instructions on how to do that, by passing the Form name as an argument to use in an Object Collection to `.Hide` it

Comment: you are my sweet god. 
PS. Why am I doing it like that? Answer is easy - different people ( :) )will use this tool and i care about dynamic update macros from my repository by macro. it's always good to learn new things, so I appreciate your help!